# Role based left menu in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is it now possible to drive the left nav menu by role? The OOTB functionality of SP2007 didn't have this capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have Audience Targeting on left navigation. I guess this is what you are looking for. Isn't it ?

Comment: think so I'll look into that.